# QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED blocking UI in iOS8?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am porting a card-melding-game from Android to iOS (see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pipperpublishing.fivekings). Each turn you choose from the drawpile or discard pile, meld your cards, and then discard. To keep it responsive, I have the computer player start pre-calculating its "best action" based on your discard, before it is apparently playing. In Android, I do my own thread management; in iOS I am trying to use GCD.

What I am finding is that the computer pre-calculations running on a `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED` queue sometimes blocks the UI, especially when testing on iOS8 on an iPhone 6. I can barely imagine that happening for `USER_INTERACTIVE`. otoh, I've read some confusing stuff about GCD reusing the UI thread for such queues, so maybe I am not understanding.

Here's the relevant code:

`EasyComputerPlayer` definition of my own queue (things were even slower when I used a global queue):

```
class EasyComputerPlayer : Player {

    static let qos_attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)
    static let concurrentDiscardTestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.pipperpublishing.FiveKings", qos_attr)
 ...
```

Here is the pre-calculation, which is called immediately after the human player discards - `testHand.main()` does the actually calculations for the possible choices of the computer's discard if the computer picked up the card that the human just discarded.

```
override func findBestHandStart(isFinalTurn : Bool, addedCard : Card) {
    let cardsWithAdded : CardList = CardList(cardList: hand!);
    cardsWithAdded.add(addedCard);

    //Create the different test hands
    testHandSets[method.rawValue].removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    for disCard in cardsWithAdded.cards {
        let cards : CardList = CardList(cardList: cardsWithAdded);
        cards.remove(disCard);
        testHandSets[method.rawValue].append(ThreadedHand(parent: self, roundOf: self.hand!.getRoundOf(), cards: cards, discard: disCard, method: self.method, isFinalTurn: isFinalTurn)) //creates new hand with replaced cards
    }

    //and then dispatch them 
    dispatchGroups[method.rawValue] = dispatch_group_create()
    for (iTask,testHand) in testHandSets[method.rawValue].enumerate(){
        let card = testHand.hand.discard
        dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroups[method.rawValue])
        dispatch_async(EasyComputerPlayer.concurrentDiscardTestQueue) {
            testHand.main() //calls meldAndEvaluate
            dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroups[self.method.rawValue])
        }
    }

}
```

In the log, I will see the tasks dispatched, and then the UI *sometimes* hangs until they all finish (which in later rounds can take 5 seconds).

I replaced `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED` with `QOS_CLASS_UTILITY` which seems to have fixed the problem temporarily, but of course I am worried that I have just reduced the frequency :)

Comment: I suggest that, when it hangs, pause your app in the debugger and examine what is actually happening on the main thread.

Comment: I agree that the problem is unlikely to be user_initiated vs utility, but rather something else (e.g. using up too many worker threads, something else blocking the main thread, etc.). I know this is an old question, but if you still want help, we need a [reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're not likely to be able to reproduce the problem with the above code.